# Flutter - Filter Stream based on Date picked

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple flutter application where I retrieve a bunch of records from Firebase. The records contain a field called DATE, which is in DateTime format.(Date + time + TZ)

But from my application, How can I make a page where I can filter the records just for a selected DATE.
When I use `.where('time', isGreaterThan : _selectedDate)` , it works. But it  gives all days after the selected date. I just want to filter for just ONE selected day.

Heres my Code:

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> _getCurrentOders() async* {

   yield* FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('ItemList')
        .where('time', isGreaterThan: _selectedDate)
        .orderBy('time', descending: false)
        .snapshots();
  }
```

I also use a DateTime picker to select a date.

```
DateTimeField(
              initialValue: DateTime.now(),
              onChanged: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedDate = val;
                });
               
              },
              format: format,
              onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) {
                return showDatePicker(
                    context: context,
                    firstDate: DateTime(2019),
                    initialDate: currentValue ?? DateTime.now(),
                    lastDate: DateTime(2100));
              },
            ),
```

Thank you for the support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// this gives you the first millisecond of the day    
var startOfTheDay = DateTime(_selectedDate.year, _selectedDate.month, _selectedDate.day);

//and this gives you the first millisecond of the next day   
var endOfTheDay = startOfTheDay.add(Duration(days: 1);
```

and after that you can use:

```
.where('time', isGreaterThan : startOfTheDay).where('time', isLessThan : endOfTheDay)
```

Comment: oops... Never thought of that! Thank you so much man. it works.